# Analytic function with assigned zeros

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Is there an example of an analytic function in the unit disc whose zeros are only the points $z_n=1-1/n$?

Comment: If there is such a function it should be $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (z-z_n)$.

Comment: @azarel: that doesn't converge.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another one:
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right)}
$$
This is analytic in the plane, except one point $z=1$, and has zeros exactly $1-1/n$, $n=1,2,3\dots$.  Unlike Henning's, which also has zeros ${} \gt 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the examples given, but how did you come to it? Maybe Henning's could have come to mind, but how did you think about this  in general?

Comment: I think it's just a matter of already knowing $1/\Gamma(z)$ as a standard example of a holomorphic function whose zeroes form a singly infinite arithmetic sequence.

Answer (score 3):

How about $f(z) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{1-z})$?

Answer (score 3):

For the general question of functions with prescribed zeros, consider [Weierstraß' factorization theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem).

Comment: Weierstrass factorization theorem is usually stated for *entire* functions, though.

Comment: True - I refered to this sentence from the Wikipedia page: "The theorem generalizes to the following: sequences in open subsets (and hence regions) of the Riemann sphere have associated functions that are holomorphic in those subsets and have zeroes at the points of the sequence."

Comment: Just use a fractional linear transformation to go from a question about a sequence of prescribed zeros with a finite limit $\alpha$ to a sequence of prescribed zeros with a limit of $\infty$: get an entire function, and transform it back (obtaining a function analytic on ${\mathbb C} \backslash \{ \alpha \}$).